# menu, header and footer is not shown in the appearance after creating the child theme

Tags: child-theme

[image: There is not menu and other so that i can edit easily...]

I created a child theme, and while I'm on my path I got some error. I checked on google but could not find the specific one. I did not get the menu , header and other under the appearance.Thanks in advance.

`functions.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

function mychildtheme_enqueue_styles() {
  $parent_style = 'parent-style';

  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
  );
 }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_enqueue_styles' );


?>
```

And `style.css` looks like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: TwentySeventeen Child
Description: The custom theme Twenty Seventeen Child using the parent theme 
Twenty Seventeen.
Author: Suman Mali
Author URI: http://nepgeeks.com/
Template: twentyseventeen
Version: 1
*/
```

Comment: if you think, that the cause of error is your child theme, then update your question with child theme files( `functions.php`, `style.css` )

Comment: updated with functions.php and style.css of child theme

Comment: <?php

function mychildtheme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_enqueue_styles' );


?>

Comment: ok. remove this from `functions.php` file: `?>`. if this wouldn't help, turn on debug mode of wordpress and provide us error logs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress